# Trying to plot time series data using time information only via lattice

Tags: r, lattice

I have a time series data for intraday price changes for different products for example:

```
Date.Time          Price Product
12/1/2012 13:12:01 15    A
12/1/2012 14:12:05 16    A
15/2/2012 09:09:10 11    B
15/2/2012 08:08:12 10    B
```

I wanted to plot this timeseries data via lattice to compare price changes between products.

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Price~as.POSIXct(strptime(Date.Time, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))|Product, data=temp, type="o")
```

Because the the day for each product can be several days apart, i would not be able to visualize the price changes over time.

[image]

I would like to just plot the time info instead of the full date time info.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It may be the morning talking, but what do you mean by "time info instead of the full data time info"?

Comment: Sorry about the typo, i meant full date info (1/15/2012 08:08:12) versus time info (08:08:12)

Comment: I would make another variable, something along the lines of `object$newvariable <- with(object, format(Date.Time, format = "%H:%M:%S"))` and plot that.